# getting a C++ Programm run under ROS

Tags: c++, ros-fuerte

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hi Im trying to write a RTSP Client for ROS and found live555.com site and there openRTSP / testRTSPClient wich are command line tools that already do what i want. So i thought should not be to hard get that running in ROS. So I created a new package and ctrl+C/V the main file in the src folder and the rest in the Include folder
when i try to Compile it now it does not find all the headers. and im dont know how to tell ROS where it should look for all the .hh files.

I tryed adding them in the Cmakelist.txt file with add_subdirectory and include_directories bot it did not work.

So my next try was to move all .cpp and .hh files from all folders/subfolders into the src folder and now I get "undefined reference to" errors for all funktions

I started with ROS a week ago so maybe its some basic thing i missed in the tutorials.

would be nice if someone could help me

EDIT:

that testRTSP .cpp is a Command line tool wich depends on some librarys and allows me to access an rtps- stream. so my plan was to send that stream over a image pipeline to openCV. but i have no idea what i need to change to compile that code with rosmake.

So i have my src/maintest.cpp file wich includes livemedia.hh
livemedia.hh is located at ../livemedia/include/livemedia.hh

livemedia itself creates a liblivemedia.a file when compiled.

So do i have to make a livemedia ros package first so it creates a libary? when yes how do i create a library.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/61136/getting-a-c++-programm-run-under-ros/) by [Stiebi](https://answers.ros.org/users/4715/stiebi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2013-04-19

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2013-04-19**:
You need to be more explicit about what exactly you did and what exactly your errors are as a result of every step.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

1. Create a Package:
   http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/Tutorials/CreatingPackage
2. go in the CMakeLists.txt and add following line:

   rosbuild_add_executable (example src/example.cpp)
   target_link_libraries(example ${PCL_LIBRARIES})

PCL is only an example Library.
Make sure that your cpp file is placed in src/..

The last step is only to call rosmake [pkg-name]

---

Originally posted by [Waterplant](https://answers.ros.org/users/4689/waterplant/) with karma: 90 on 2013-04-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Stiebi](https://answers.ros.org/users/4715/stiebi/) on 2013-04-19**:
thx for your answer but it did not help. im editing my post and make it more specific

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You are supposed to put all .cpp files into src/ and the headers to include/mypackagename/

If you are lazy and your headers are not needed from the outside, you can also put them in the src folder. Then you can include them as `#include "myclass.h"` instead of `#include <mypackagename/myclass.h>`

The *undefined reference* error is from the linker, which doesn't know where the executable code for the functionality defined in the headers is. This means you either didn't specify a required library or didn't compile all your code.

For the former see Waterplants answer, for the latter make sure you add all your .cpp files to the rosbuild_add_executable command in CMakeLists.txt, e.g.

```
rosbuild_add_executable (programname src/main.cpp src/somethingelse.cpp src/myclass.cpp)
```

---

Originally posted by [Felix Endres](https://answers.ros.org/users/113/felix-endres/) with karma: 6468 on 2013-04-19

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Stiebi](https://answers.ros.org/users/4715/stiebi/) on 2013-04-19**:
already tryed to put all .cpp and .hh files in the src folder but did not work . how do i specify the linker where it finds all the code. what you mean with library? all i use is roscpp as i just have cpp files

**Comment by [Felix Endres](https://answers.ros.org/users/113/felix-endres/) on 2013-04-19**:
Can you please post the content of your CMakeLists.txt